# Group tags by month using MongoDB/Mongoose.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

My collection in mongodb looks like below:

**Post:**

```
// ...
 tags: [
        {
            id: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'Tag',
                required: true,
            }
            // ... 
        }
 ],

 date: {
    type: Date,
 }
// ...
```

I want to write a query which results the below result:

```
[
    {
      "month": "Jan",
      "tag1": 5,
      "tag2": 80,
      // ...
     }, 
    {
      "month": "Feb",
      "tag1": 30,
      "tag2": 95,
      // ...
    },
    // ...
]
```

I think I need to use aggregation. Is it right?

I wrote this but the result is not that I want.

```
  const monthStrings = ["", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  Posst.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        $expr: {
          $and: [
            { $gt: ["$created_at", oneYearFromNow] },
            { $lt: ["$created_at", dateNow] }
          ],
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          month: { $month: "$date" },
          year: { $year: "$date" },
        },
        count: {
          $sum: 1
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: {
          $concat: [
            {
              $arrayElemAt: [
                monthStrings,
                "$_id.month"
              ]
            },
            "-",
            "$_id.year"
          ]
        },
        count: 1,
      }
    }
  ])
```

How can I get the result that I want?

(The returned format is not really important, but what I am trying to achieve is in a single query to retrieve a number of counts for the same grouping (one per month).)

Comment: what have you tried? add your another schema and add sample documents for both collection and add expected result from that documents.

Comment: Please check my Edit. @turivishal

Comment: it will help if you add some sample documents.

Comment: probably similar to below answer, if this helpful https://mongoplayground.net/p/RPK4X_3C-ru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to count documents for each tag, you need to group by the tag identifier. Since tags are in an array, the easiest way is to first unwind the array before grouping. Finally, in order to get all tags for the same month in a single document, you need to perform a second group operation. For example (assuming the name of the tag you want to use is in the "ref" field):

```
Posst.aggregate([
  {
    $match: ... 
  },
  {
    // Unwind the tags array, produces one document for each element in the array
    $unwind: '$tags'
  },
  {
    // Group by month, year and tag reference
    $group: {
      _id: {
        month: { $month: '$date' },
        year: { $year: '$date' },
        tag: '$tag.ref'
      },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    // Group again by month and year to aggregate all tags in one document
    $group: {
      _id: {
        month: '$_id.month',
        year: '$_id.year'
      },
      // Collect tag counts into an array
      tagCounts: {
        $push: {
          k: '$_id.tag',
          v: '$count'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // Reshape document to have each tag in a separate field
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [ 
          { month: '$_id.month', year: '$_id.year' },
          { $arrayToObject: '$tagCounts' }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Great bro. Thank you